Variables Issue for apollo and gql
I am trying to use
const tagqryTypeDefs = require('./src/mongodb/tag/tagGql');

rather than
const tagqryTypeDefs =` returnAlltags: [Tag] `;

In the following function:
const typeDefs = gql`
type Query {
        findAllUser: [User]
        ${tagqryTypeDefs}
    }
`

For tagGql it has
const tagqryTypeDefs = " returnAlltags: [Tag] ";
module.exports = tagqryTypeDefs;

it always gives me the err "Error: Query.returnAlltags defined in resolvers, but not in schema", But if I am not using the require, it will work properly.
Could you help me with this issue and the reason behind? I have been trapped here for quite some time.
Any ideas or solution that allow me to import variables into gql``

Now I have a new issue coming up:
I am trying to use the variable rather than hardcode in resolver, how might I define the "tagResolverQuery" so that I can introduce it into the resolver like this
const { tagdbTypeDefs, tagqryTypeDefs, tagmutTypeDefs, tagResolverQuery } =require('./src/mongodb/tag/tagGql');

const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        tagResolverQueryN,
        // returnAlltags: async () => {
        //     return tagModel.find({});
        // },
    },
}

I tried to put it like this but it didn't work
const tagResolverQuery = {
    returnAlltags: async () => {
        // return client.db.tags.find({});
        return tagModel.find({});
    },
}

Resolved mhyself using spread syntax
...tagResolverQuery

